# Configuring SSL communication with client custom cipher suite

Tags: security, authentication, ssl, openssl, client-server

I have a requirement to use the cipher suite: **DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384**
I configured to use the required cipher suite on both server and client. During tests, I noticed that the handshake is failing between server and client.

On server I reset the configuration to accept any cipher suite, but on the client I retained the cipher suite string as per the requirement. Even now the handshake fails.

I took tcpdump and analyzed using wireshark. I noticed that client is sending the cipher suite string, but server is not accepting and hence handshake fails and connection is not established.

As per openssl documentation for the cipher suite: DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, Kx is DH and Au is RSA. Hence for authentication purposes I created a certificate with RSA key (AES encryption and SHA2 hashing)

What am I missing here. Could you please help.

Comment: Did you set up DH parameter?

Comment: I have already tried that. I followed the procedure mentioned in the below link.
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44251/openssl-generate-different-type-of-self-signed-certificate

In this case the certificate itself is not read. In logs I see the following errors

SSL routines:SSL_SET_CERT:unknown certificate type.

SSL server certificate not found, or password is wrong - SSL ports will not be opened

Comment: can you show the code where you setup DH parameters? If you check s_server and s_client, for DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, connection is through for TLS 1.2

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).